# How to export XML from mfg/pro V9?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I use DATASET to export XML in progress.

my code:

```
/*declare and create DATASET*/

DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttLASRow NO-UNDO 
FIELD temp_wonbr AS CHARACTER 
FIELD temp_id    AS CHARACTER.

DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttAllocations NO-UNDO     
FIELD parentid AS RECID SERIALIZE-HIDDEN. 

DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttAllocDetails NO-UNDO   
FIELD parentId    AS RECID SERIALIZE-HIDDEN 
FIELD Emplacement AS CHARACTER
FIELD Reference   AS CHARACTER 
FIELD NumLot      AS INTEGER
FIELD ExpDat      AS CHARACTER 
FIELD Qalloc      AS INTEGER 
FIELD msg         AS CHARACTER .

DEFINE DATASET dsLAS  FOR ttLasRow, ttAllocations, 
ttAllocDetails
PARENT-ID-RELATION FOR ttLasRow, ttAllocations PARENT-ID-FIELD parentId
PARENT-ID-RELATION FOR ttAllocations, ttAllocDetails PARENT-ID-FIELD parentId
.

/*Export XML*/

DATASET dsLAS:WRITE-XML("file", "c:\temp\xml.xml").
```

But it doesn't work on Progress V9.1E04 ( QAD mfg/pro V9.0 SP2) .
Error :

```
Unable to understand after -- "DEFINE". (247) ( understand " DATASET" )                          x
x x** Invalid statement. (254)                                                x
x x**  Could not understand line 18. (198)
```

Please support!

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a useful description of an issue. What happens? Any error message?

Comment: Also please add your Version of OpenEdge to the question

Answer (score 1):

datasets were introduced in Progress OpenEdge 10.0A - see http://www.oehive.org/VersionHistory.html.

You can connect a one major version higher client to your database, so assuming your **database** is also 9.1E then you can use a 10.2B client to execute your export.

If your database is actually an 8.3 database and you are already trying to get the most out of this ancient tech with a 9.1E client, then you are - without all sorts of tricks like updating a copy of the database - out of luck.